# python numba fingerprint error

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I'm attempting numba to optimise some code. I've worked through the initial examples in section 1.3.1 in the 0.26.0 user guide (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.26.0/user/jit.html) and get the expected results, so I don't think the problem is installation.

Here's my code:

```
import numba
import numpy
import random

a = 8
b = 4

def my_function(a, b):
    all_values = numpy.fromiter(range(a), dtype = int)
    my_array = []
    for n in (range(a)):
        some_values = (all_values[all_values != n]).tolist()
        c = random.sample(some_values, b)
        my_array.append(sorted([n] + c))
    return my_array

print(my_function(a, b))

my_function_numba = numba.jit()(my_function)

print(my_function_numba(a, b))
```

Which after printing out the expected results from the my_function call returns the following error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b5d8983a58f6> in <module>()
     19 my_function_numba = numba.jit()(my_function)
     20 
---> 21 print(my_function_numba(a, b))

ValueError: cannot compute fingerprint of empty list
```

Fingerprint of empty list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about that error in particular, but in general, to be fast `numba` requires a particular subset of numpy/python (see [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.26.0/reference/pysupported.html) and [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.26.0/reference/numpysupported.html) for more).  So I might rewrite it like this.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def fast_my_function(a, b):
    all_values = np.arange(a)
    my_array = np.empty((a, b + 1), dtype=np.int32)
    for n in range(a):
        some = all_values[all_values != n]
        c = np.empty(b + 1, dtype=np.int32)
        c[1:] = np.random.choice(some, b)
        c[0] = n
        c.sort()
        my_array[n, :] = c
    return my_array
```

Main things to note:

1. no lists, I'm pre-allocating everything.
2. no use of generators  (in both python 2 & 3 `for n in range(a)` will get converted to a fast native loop)
3. adding `nopython=True` to the decorator makes it so numba will complain if I use something that can't be efficiently JITed.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks. And I've gone from 91.3 microseconds to 12 microseconds. Any reason why c = np.empty(b + 1, dtype=np.int32) and not c = np.empty(a, dtype=np.int32)?

Comment: In your code above `c` is length `b`, then you add `[n]` to it before appending, so I think that's the right shape?

Comment: Yup. Thanks again!